# Combining csv files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to combine multiple csv files into 1 with PowerShell, the process works fine, but it is adding strange characters at the beginning of the output file which gets rejected into the system it is going into? here is the command I am using:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ATR\*.csv | foreach { Get-Content $_ } | sort -Unique | Out-File C:\ATR\fileX.csv -Encoding utf8
```

Here is the problem:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try Set-Content instead of Out-File and see if the same is true.

Comment: Yes, exact same result on Set-Content

Comment: Look at the source file containing that like.  What is the encoding there. My thinking is it's probably wrong to start. If that's the case you can either fix it in place or convert it to Unicode on the fly.

Comment: There are 6 source files, but none of them have those leading characters, it only pops in on the merge. I can merge them manually with a bat file, and that does not happen, only in my powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it, I removed the Encoding UTF8 from the end of the statement and it seems to remove the characters, I will have to test my upload now to see if the AS400 will accept it.

Comment: Sounds like they were ASCII in the first place.